# ServiceRoute in ASP.NET MVC with areas intercepts ActionLink to Home

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have an MVC 3 application with areas, and I am exposing a service from a specific area and controller. The routing to this service is defined inside the AreaRegistration like this

```
public class AreaAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get { return "Area"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.Routes.Add(
            new ServiceRoute("Area/Controller/Service",
                new NinjectServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyService)));

        // ....
    }
}
```

In my `Global.asax.cs` I only define a default route

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

In my `_Layout.chshtml` I have a link to my home page, where I give an empty area, and I expect it to find the `Index` action in the `HomeController` in the `Controllers` folder at the top (outside the Areas folder):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)
```

For some reason this `ActionLink` renders as

```
~/Area/Controller/Service?action=Index&controller=Home
```

If I comment out the ServiceRoute, the same `ActionLink` points to `~/` which is what I expect.

Any ideas how to fix this routing issue? The only workaround I have found is to use this instead:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/")">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

We were having this exact same problem. The order of route registration appears to be the issue, in that routes from areas will be registered before routes from the global.asax code.

To fix this issue, allowing the URL route to the service as well as preventing the postback from being targeted at the service URL try moving the ServiceRoute addition into the Global.asax.cs after the other route is registered.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    context.Routes.Add(
        new ServiceRoute("Area/Controller/Service",
            new NinjectServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyService)));

}
```

This worked for us, but does of course come at the overhead of putting code pertaining to the area in the main project.